# How to compute KL divergence in diffusion model?

Tags: diffusion-models

In the original [DDPM paper](https://ar5iv.org/abs/2006.11239), the author suggested we can set $ \sum_{\theta} $ to a fixed value. But in the [Improved DDPM paper](https://ar5iv.labs.arxiv.org/html/2102.09672), the author said learning the $ \sum_{\theta} $ could improve the model's log-likelihood performance, and they introduced the $ L_{vlb} $ term to the loss to achieve that.

The $ L_{vlb} $ term used the KL-divergence function. However, I could figure out what I needed to do to compute that value in code. I checked the [code for the paper](https://github.com/openai/improved-diffusion/tree/main/improved_diffusion). I think their code has changed a lot since they published the paper, and I could not associate the code with the paper.

Assuming I already implemented the basic DDPM algorithm and have the $ \epsilon_{\theta} $, what variables and formula do I need to compute $ D_{KL} $?